# ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'blooddonarapp'

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1049

i'm using AWS binami Ubuntu 14.04 and mysql 5.6.29. i was created database **BloodDonarApp** but after some day when using **show databases** command its listing databases but while i'm use database it showing  **ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'blooddonarapp'** below i mentioned my terminal result.
For this any solution is there. Thanks for advance.

```
  mysql> show databases;
    +--------------------+
    | Database           |
    +--------------------+
    | information_schema |
    | ATM                |
    | BloodDonarApp      |
    | FixMyRide          |
    | NEG                |
    | NVgoods            |
    | PMS                |
    | Translogix         |
    | kishore            |
    | mysql              |
    | performance_schema |
    | sample             |
    | test               |
    | vasanth            |
    +--------------------+
    14 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> use BloodDonarApp;
    ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'blooddonarapp'
    mysql>
```

Comment: could  be name containg not visible char  ..try check the length  ..of the string

Comment: Do you have anything like `lower_case_table_names` in your /etc/my.cnf? Basically MySQL is not key sensitive but... Out of couriosity did you test the other databases? Like: use translogix instead of Translogix? Are you sure that the mysql user has rights to actually use the database?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Create new database in lower case.
2. Dump structure and data from camel case db.
3. Execute dump into lower case db.
4. Try to use db again.

MySQL transform schema name to lower case and then compare with existing schemes.

Those steps will fix your problem.

Thanks

Comment: as follow you given i tried but its show new database and new schema also like DB name OLD : BloodDonarApp & NEW :   blooddonarapp         SCHEMA name like OLD : BloodDonarApp & NEW :   blooddonarapp

Comment: @Krish Create schema blooddonarapp_new to prevent any collusion

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how MySQL was installed, it is possible that the default MySQL database was NOT created.
This may be checked by looking in /var/lib/mysql for a mysql subfolder (i.e. /var/lib/mysql/mysql ). If the path does NOT contain a mysql subfolder, it needs to be created by completing the following steps:

rcmysql stop
pkill mysql   (NOTE: wait until notification is given that mysqld ended, then hit )
/usr/bin/mysql_install_db

Now that the above steps have been run, check and make sure that the database was created:

cd /var/lib/mysql
ls -al | grep mysql

In the listing output there should now be a folder called mysql.  Finally, the correct owner and group need to be set on the mysql folder.

chown mysql:mysql mysql

Restart the mysql service in safe mode again and attempt the initial command again:

mysql --user=root mysql